# Submit Input Through <DIV>

Tags: php, html, email, input

Hi I've checked stack overflow for duplicates but can't find any or just can't specify it correctly so here I am...

I have these inputs and I am trying to get them e-mailed to me with PHP

```
<div id="inputBox">
 <input class="input" type="text" name="email" value="Email address" onfocus="if (this.value=='Email address') this.value='';">
 <input id="passPut" class="input" type="text" name="password" value="Password" onfocus="if (this.value=='Password') this.value='';">
</div>
```

They're not in any form tags as you can see anyways, here's the button I want to use to submit this information:

```
<div id="logIn"><strong>Send</strong></div>
```

So the question is how do I get the PHP below to send WHEN the button is clicked...

```
<?php

  $email = $_POST ['email'];
  $password = $_POST ['password'];

  $to = "myemaily@gmail.com";
  $subject = "Submission Acquired";

  mail ($to, $subject, , "From " . $email . $password);

  ?>
```

I really don't know if there's anything wrong here as this is the best I know but if there are alternatives please let me know.

PLEASE NOTE: I am using a div as a button as I have a design for it so I am better off avoiding button tags.

Thanks to everyone in advance!

Comment: form, in order to by submitted either needs to have a `type="submit"`, or an ajax submit. Where are you doing the ajax submit ?

Comment: You either need to wrap it in a `<form>` with method post, or have a `<button>` that submits your data with JavaScript.

Comment: okay can someone offer an answer with the <form> method=Post way?

Comment: Ajax is the solutiom and google is your best friend you can find many good tutorials, help yourself first n if you face any problem ask for help, stackoverflow is not coding setvice

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly basic question, and you should probably start with a php tutorial, but here's a starter.

Your form would do something like this:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />

</form>
```

and the php (in its simplest form) would look like this:

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

  $email = $_POST ['email'];
  $password = $_POST ['password'];

  $to = "myemaily@gmail.com";
  $subject = "Submission Acquired";

  $msg  = "this is the email text";

  mail ($to, $subject, $msg, 'From:' . $email );
  }
  ?>
```

you should be able to figure out the rest yourself.

**Edit:**  You can still use the system you are using, but instead of div tags, you would just use a `<button>` tag, but it would need to live inside the from tags to work. this can be styled however you like using css.    must make sure your tag is something like `<button id="submit" name="submit">submit</button>` and you can style it off the id, and still check to see whether it has been clicked with similar methods.  Here's a good example [PHP form example](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_complete.asp)

Comment: I placed that input you showed and that's the first part done - thanks.

Comment: But does that mean that, as my PHP is below the input button (exactly the one you coded) it will work and send the information straight out to the email?

Comment: you still need the form.  I added a message text variable.  Note:  it's a very bad idea to send passwords through email, so I left that out.

Comment: i know im a noob, this is just a one off programming topic for college and im trying to make it good...

Comment: how do i add the form?

Comment: you can put it in your html instead of the divs.  your other inputs that you have already created would exist inside the form tags. if the php form you are calling is not in the same script, just change the `action` tag to the the php script (e.g. action="email.php" )

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you're going through way too much trouble for a place holder. Instead of that value="Email Address" onfocus="..." Simply put placeholder="Email Address". About your question, you need a form to submit to PHP. Code:

index.php:

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['submitButton')){
    if(isset($_POST['myInput') && !empty($_POST['myInput') && isset($_POST['passwordInput']) && !empty($_POST['passwordInput'])){
mail(); //Enter parameters  
    }
}
?>

<form method="POST"    action="index.php"> 

<input type="text" name="myInput" placeholder="Email Address"> 
<input type="password" name="passwordInput" placeholder="Password">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submitButton">

</form>
```

Edit: Added more details in terms of post.